# Cannot use Alt-Gr characters on Swedish keyboard (e.g. Alt-Gr + 2 should print @ symbol)

Tags: localization, iterm2

I have a Swedish language keyboard. Some important characters such as "@" and "$" require combining the right hand alt button with numbers.

This used to work; either I have messed up my settings or an update has broken it. In MacOS preferences are region=UK, keyboard=SwedishPro. In MacOS terminal.app the Alt-Gr button combos still work as normal. 
In iTerm2 preferences->profiles->(profile-name)->terminal -Character Encoding is the default "UFT8," -Environment is set to "Set local variables locally" (I've tried turning this off but it doesn't fix the issue)
I have icu4c in my .zshrc path, but I removed it and it didn't fix the issue.

Strangely "alt-gr + ¨ = ~" still works. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue and solved it by:

1. Going to `Preferences -> Profiles -> Your profile name -> Keys`
2. Setting `Right Option Key` to `Normal`.

Hope the solution applies to you.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I had accidentally messed up <kbd>Al tGr</kbd> on my Finnish keyboard by defining a navigation shortcut (*iTerm2* `Preferences` > `Keys` > `Navigation Shortcuts`) that remapped <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + Number.

The last line in the question suggests that this might be the culprit in your case as well:

> Strangely "alt-gr + ¨ = ~" still works. Any help greatly appreciated."